# Unable to check outdated global npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm going through an npm tutorial and one command we are learning is `npm outdated -g` to check if any global packages are out of date.

Whenever I run that command, I get the error:

```sh
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/samlegros/.npm/_logs/2019-03-28T00_46_47_834Z-debug.log
```

I am running `npm 6.9.0` and `node 10.15.2`.

Here is the error log associated with it:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'outdated', '-g' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.15.2
4 verbose npm-session bc4abe7eb4488494
5 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator 273ms (from cache)
6 silly pacote registry packument for express-generator@^4.16.0 fetched in 284ms
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server 278ms (from cache)
8 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table 274ms (from cache)
9 silly pacote registry packument for http-server@^0.11.1 fetched in 291ms
10 silly pacote registry packument for text-table@^0.2.0 fetched in 290ms
11 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint 278ms (from cache)
12 silly pacote registry packument for jshint@^2.10.1 fetched in 292ms
13 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-dev 280ms (from cache)
14 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli 285ms (from cache)
15 silly pacote registry packument for node-dev@^3.1.3 fetched in 294ms
16 silly pacote registry packument for grunt-cli@^1.3.2 fetched in 295ms
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 289ms (from cache)
18 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sequelize-cli 283ms (from cache)
19 silly pacote registry packument for create-react-app@^2.1.8 fetched in 301ms
20-31...
32 silly pacote registry packument for ionic@^3.20.0 fetched in 344ms
33 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova 350ms (from cache)
34 silly pacote registry packument for cordova@^8.0.0 fetched in 370ms
35 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 364ms (from cache)
36 silly pacote registry packument for npm@^6.9.0 fetched in 391ms
37 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
37 verbose stack     at dotindex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table/index.js:59:32)
37 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table/index.js:11:21
37 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
37 verbose stack     at forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table/index.js:73:31)
37 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table/index.js:10:9
37 verbose stack     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
37 verbose stack     at reduce (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table/index.js:63:30)
37 verbose stack     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table/index.js:9:20)
37 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:130:16
37 verbose stack     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
37 verbose stack     at outdated_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:221:12)
37 verbose stack     at skip (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:343:5)
37 verbose stack     at updateDeps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js:446:7)
37 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
37 verbose stack     at Promise.successAdapter [as _fulfillmentHandler0] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeify.js:23:30)
37 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:21)
38 verbose cwd /Users/samlegros/Documents/Development/Tutorials/lynda-become-a-mern-stack-javascript-developer/learning-npm-the-node-package-manager/exercise-files/CH2/02_01/start
39 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
40 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "outdated" "-g"
41 verbose node v10.15.2
42 verbose npm  v6.9.0
43 error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
44 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to npm-cli on github there was an issue with npm outdated. It was fixed a couple of weeks ago so you likely have to wait until the next update of npm comes out for the fix to be released.

Link: [npm outdated fix](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/173)

Comment: Fix released in [6.9.1](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/CHANGELOG.md#v691-2019-06-26). Upgrade npm with `npm i -g npm@latest`